# RAILS Arquivo Seed Roda, mas Não Salva O dados no Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou criando um arquivo **seeds** para popular meu banco de dados, esse arquivo é responsável por popular os `Grupos(model :grupo)` que roda sem problema e também popular `TipoAtividade(model :tipo_atividade)`, que pertence ao grupo.
[image: classe ruby Grupo]
[image: classe ruby TipoAtividade]

Quando eu rodo o rake `db:seed` ele roda normalmente e gera os grupos e aparenta ter gerado os tipos também, logo abaixo o codigo do arquivo seeds.
[image: classe ruby Seed]

Porém quando vou olhar o banco de dados é isso que aparece.
[image: tabela tipo de atividade]

Ele cria uma linha no banco de dados, mas não salva os dados nas colunas nome e a referência de `grupo(grupo_id)`.
 Gostaria de saber o que está acontecendo, pois já pesquisei na internet e não achei nada que fosse muito claro sobre esse problema. Cheguei a ver algo de "protected_attributes", mas a gem conflita com certas versões do rails e/ou do bundler, não consegui identificar.

Caso a pergunta não fique clara é so pedir que eu edito.

Comment: Se a resposta abaixo deu certo. Você deve marcar ela como "resolvida".

Answer (score 1):

No exemplo acima você criou 3 grupos.
A classe Grupo tem um relacionamento `has_many :tipo_atividades`

Você deve ter a instância de um `Grupo` exemplo:

```
# pegando o útimo grupo criado
grupo3 = Grupo.last
grupo3.tipo_atividades.create(nome: 'Palestra')
```

ou então

```
# pegando os últimos 3 grupos criados
Grupo.last(3).each do |grupo|
  grupo.tipo_atividades.create(nome: 'Palestra')
end
```

[Utilizando o método has_many](https://nandovieira.com.br/relacionamento-muitos-para-muitos-com-activerecord-no-rails)

Comment: AH SIM !! Deu certo, mto obg Danilo

Comment: show de bola!!!!